# How to model the effect of an intervention on survival times?

Tags: survival

I have data that includes the survival times as well as the times of an intervention.
I believe that the intervention will shorten survival times i.e. increase the hazard ratio for some time period following the intervention, after which the effect of the intervention will wear off.
I would like to find out whether this intervention increases the hazard rate, and if so what is the time-profile of the effect.
How can this be modeled most accurately?
Thanks!

Comment: Part III of Hernán, M. A., & Robins, J. M. (2020). [*Causal Inference: What If*](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/). Chapman & Hall/CRC is devoted to counterfactual formal causal inference in longitudinal models, including survival time models. I suspect that especially of note for you in this book is **Fine Point 17.2: The hazards of hazard ratios** (tl;dr hazard ratios have no valid causal interpretation).

Answer (score -1):

Usually when the question is whether an intervention affects the survival time, then time-dependent methods are generally required. The simplest case is when there is a single predictor, like an intervention. In this can one can use a Kaplan-Meier method to compare survival times between the interventions. If there are many predictors (e.g. age, gender, disease severity, etc...) then a regression approach is generally used and the most commonly utilized model is the Cox proportional hazards model (but it has some assumptions that you have to check).

For example, let's assume your data is in a file called `mydata` and looks something like this:

| id | time | status | intervention |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | A |
| 3 | 4 | 0 | A |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | B |

where

`id` - The variable identifying each subject

`time` - The follow-up time from the start of the intervention until an event occurs (i.e. death in your example) or last follow-up. For example, if you got your intervention on 1/1/2020 and died on 1/1/2021, your time would be 1 year or 365 days. If you got your intervention on 12/1/2020 and then study ended on 1/1/2021, then your time would be 31 days.

`status` - Indicates what happened at the follow-up time, 1 = death and 0 = censored (meaning the subject did not die and you don't know what will happen in the future).

`intervention` - The intervention (A or B in this example).

Ideally, you would have as many subjects as possible in your dataset. In R one would could fit a model to this using the survival package (there are many alternatives, but this is the standard go-to option).

`fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ intervention, data = mydata)`

This would generate a Kaplan-Meier type model of your data stored in an object called `fit`.

---

A classic example dataset in the `survival` library called `aml` and can be used to demonstrate using real data.

```
> library(survival)
> data(aml)
> aml
   time status             x
1     9      1    Maintained
2    13      1    Maintained
3    13      0    Maintained
4    18      1    Maintained
5    23      1    Maintained
6    28      0    Maintained
7    31      1    Maintained
8    34      1    Maintained
9    45      0    Maintained
10   48      1    Maintained
11  161      0    Maintained
12    5      1 Nonmaintained
13    5      1 Nonmaintained
14    8      1 Nonmaintained
15    8      1 Nonmaintained
16   12      1 Nonmaintained
17   16      0 Nonmaintained
18   23      1 Nonmaintained
19   27      1 Nonmaintained
20   30      1 Nonmaintained
21   33      1 Nonmaintained
22   43      1 Nonmaintained
23   45      1 Nonmaintained
```

There are 23 subjects in this dataset and the treatment/intervention is called `x`. We fit the Kaplan-Meier model.

```
> fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
> print(fit)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)

                 n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
x=Maintained    11      7     31      18      NA
x=Nonmaintained 12     11     23       8      NA
```

The output shows the survival time for each treatment arm. Maintained subjects have a median survival of 31 months and non-maintained have a median survival of 23 months. You can compare the plots of these survival curves.

```
> plot(fit)
```

Finally, you can test whether these curves are really different from one another using a logrank test.

```
> survdiff(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml, rho = 0)
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml, rho = 0)

                 N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
x=Maintained    11        7    10.69      1.27       3.4
x=Nonmaintained 12       11     7.31      1.86       3.4

 Chisq= 3.4  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.07
```

Read more on this and related topics:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/survival-analysis-R

Comment: The question's author already appears to know about event history models, and appears interested specifically in *causal inference* in event history models. (Also: welcome to CV, Brant Inman!)

Comment: One additional and very useful exercise that might apply to the user's question is to examine the hazard function visually. In R this can be done using the `bshazard` and `muhaz` packages, among others. It is very interesting in many applications to understand how the hazard function is changing over time. This could inform the use of flexible models for the baseline hazard, like the Royston-Parmar model.